# Sending an AlchemyData News query using Node.js (watson-developer-cloud module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I'm currently working with Node.js using the watson-developer-cloud Node.js SDK and I'm having problems when sending a query that includes an entity.

This is my code:

```
// require watson's node sdk and fs
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var fs = require('fs');

// Define output file
var outputJSONFile = '/home/vagrant/Desktop/node/dir/data.json';

// Create alchemy_data_news object using our api_key
var alchemy_data_news = watson.alchemy_data_news({
  api_key: ''
});

// Define params for the query and what values to return
// Accepted returne values:
// docs.alchemyapi.com/v1.0/docs/full-list-of-supported-news-api-fields
var params = {
  start: 'now-1m',
  end: 'now',
  count: 2,
  qs: ['q.enriched.url.enrichedTitle.entities.entity.text=apple'],
  return: ['enriched.url.url,enriched.url.title']
};

// Call getNews method and return json
alchemy_data_news.getNews(params, function (err, news) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error:', err);
  } else {
    fs.writeFile(outputJSONFile, JSON.stringify(news, null, 2), function(err)   {
      if (err) {
        console.log('WriteFile Error:', err);
      } else {
        console.log("JSON saved to " + outputJSONFile);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to send the entities parameters using the **params** object.

While digging up through some code I came across **qs** so I have been using that to test but I haven't had success at all.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

P.S: I'm trying to pass:
**q.enriched.url.enrichedTitle.entities.entity.text=apple**
**q.enriched.url.enrichedTitle.entities.entity.type=company**

Comment: It seems like with this change the code is now working properly:

var params = {
  ...
  ...
  'q.enriched.url.enrichedTitle.entities.entity.text': 'Apple',
  'q.enriched.url.enrichedTitle.entities.entity.type': 'company',
  ...
};

If there's a better way, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [node-sdk source code for AlchemyDataNews](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/blob/master/services/alchemy_data_news/v1.js#L68), you will see that the top level parameters are being sent as query strings.
Then `params` map should be:

```
var params = {
  start: 'now-1m',
  end: 'now',
  count: 2,
  return: ['enriched.url.url,enriched.url.title'],
  // fields here 
  'q.enriched.url.enrichedTitle.entities.entity.text': 'apple',
  'q.enriched.url.enrichedTitle.entities.entity.type': 'company'
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!